# C#/Visual Studio Rename Multiple Members Simultaneously

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Does anyone know how to rename multiple members simultaneously?

I have about ~360 structs (data models) in a large legacy monolithic project and am looking to standardise the naming of the fields.

They have been named ad hoc over ~20 years and don't necessarily match data field names which causes confusion.

We've used attributes to overcome historically, but are looking to resolve this (we might still use attributes where it's not feasible to use the exact same name as the data field).

Find/replace (even using regex/external tools) is not feasible due to the common member names and massive code base.

Right now, those structs are in a massive single file "DataStructs.cs" (~20k+ lines, not ideal, but that's how it is).

It might take a few dozen dev hours to rename (F2) each individual member - too long.

We can re-generate the "DataStructs.cs" code with the names how we want - effectively renaming them in place if we copy/paste it in - but then want to be able to ask VS to update all references.

Example:

Existing:

```
namespace DataModels
{
    public struct PersonData
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "Surname")]
        public string LastName;
        [DataMember(Name = "GivenNames")]
        public string FirstName;
        ...
    }
    public struct AddressData
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "Address1")]
        public string Street1;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Replace:

```
namespace DataModels
{
    public struct PersonData
    {
        public string Surname;
        public string GivenNames;
        ...
    }
    public struct AddressData
    {
        public string Address1;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: You could probably do this with "Replace in files" and a little regular expression magic.

Comment: You could learn to create a your own [Analyzer with Code Fix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix) catering to this specific needs. But the hard truth in programming is that learning something new to automate a task usually isn't going to be faster than just doing the labour manually. But it sure is more fun!

Comment: Once you're comfortable with analyzers, [this article](https://www.tabsoverspaces.com/233534-rename-all-fields-to-start-with-underscore-roslyn-analyzer-and-codefix) will get you pretty close to what you need. Just improve it with a bit of `IFieldSymbol.GetAttributes()` to find your attribute and its value to rename the field to.